# MPAndroid Library pieChart add same value ie text and integer

Tags: java, android

I am using MPAndroid Library to create pie chart in my app, i am able take user input and display in pie chart but when user enter same value which is already in pie chart it won't displayed in pie chart and again when i enter different value, the previous value which i entered but didn't displayed will display in pie chart.

Any help will be appreciated !! Thank You.

Below is my pieChart method:

```
public void pieChart() {

    mydb = new DBHelper(this);

    try {
           //Check for table in database
           if (mydb.checkForTables()) 
            {
            stringItems.addAll(mydb.getAllItem());
            intItems.addAll(mydb.getAllAmount());
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Data table is empty.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    List<Entry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    if(intItems.size() > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < intItems.size(); i++)
            yVals1.add(new Entry(intItems.get(i), i));
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"intItem is empty !!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    List<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();

    if(stringItems.size() > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < stringItems.size(); i++)
            xVals.add(stringItems.get(i));
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"stringItem is empty !!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    // create pieDataSet
    PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(yVals1, " ");
    dataSet.setSliceSpace(3);
    dataSet.setSelectionShift(5);

    // adding colors
    List<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    // Added My Own colors
    for (int c : MY_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);


    dataSet.setColors(colors);

    //  create pie data object and set xValues and yValues and set it to the pieChart
    PieData data = new PieData(xVals, dataSet);
    //   data.setValueFormatter(new DefaultValueFormatter());
    //   data.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter());

    data.setValueFormatter(new MyValueFormatter());
    data.setValueTextSize(10f);
    data.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    mChart.setData(data);

    // undo all highlights
    mChart.highlightValues(null);

    // refresh/update pie chart
    mChart.invalidate();

    // animate piechart
    mChart.animateXY(1400, 1400);


    // Legends to show on bottom of the graph
    Legend l = mChart.getLegend();
    l.setPosition(Legend.LegendPosition.BELOW_CHART_CENTER);
    l.setXEntrySpace(7);
    l.setYEntrySpace(5);
}

private SpannableString generateCenterSpannableText() {

    SpannableString s = new SpannableString("Overview");
    s.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.7f), 0, 8, 0);
    s.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.NORMAL), 8, s.length(), 0);

    return s;
}


public class MyValueFormatter implements ValueFormatter {

    private DecimalFormat mFormat;

    public MyValueFormatter() {
        mFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,##0"); // use one decimal if needed
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        // write your logic here
        return mFormat.format(value) + ""; // e.g. append a dollar-sign
    }
}
```

Comment: People can't help you with your code if you don't in clude it. Please see[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks MikeJRamsey56